# Any suggestions on how to implement this system?

Tags: forms, uac

I need to implement a system where I have 5 forms. An agent then goes to a client and can fill one, some, or all of these forms. The client will then be able to access ONLY his forms through a backend system, while the agent has a god-eye view of the system. The client can then mark the form as accepted if it is correct, or reject it, or even add remarks to it.

The system will know who has filled out the form by using a login screen and every agent will have his username and password. This will replace the need to implement something like a signature which is very complex and nearly impossible for the web. The agent will have access to the internet via 3G.

P.S. The forms mainly contain yes/no answers and some fields require you to enter a number.

Are there any open-source packages which can let you do such a thing? Or is very similar but can obtain these results with some modifications?

I am totally lost here. Unfortunately, I don't have enough time to implement such a system from scratch. That is why it would be ideal to find a good package and attain the results I need with some modifications.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

--EDIT--

I found a web application called Formdesk (http://www.formdesk.com/) which does exactly what I need however it is not open source. Do you know of similar flexible and powerful system which is open source. I found out that such systems are called Forms Management Systems. I am currently looking for more systems like formdesk. If you know of an excellent one (preferably open source, please let me know)

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be more specific. For example which PDAs do you want to support? When the agent goes to the client will he have internet access and thus be able to use a web browser or will he need a program on a laptop to capture the forms for later upload when a connection is available?

Comment: Hi, they are tablet pcs not PDA's. Sorry, my bad, so they can use a normal browser. They will have access to the internet via 3G so everything will be web based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either Wordpress or DotNetNuke for that. These CMS (Content Management System) tools will allow you to easily create the forms UI, authentication, authorization,...etc. They contain these functions already implemented, you just have to organize and put then together to fit your needs. There is no a generic 1-click solution for your specific needs but these tools should make the journey a lot shorter.